# Doxygen for C -- multiple objects

Tags: c, object, doxygen

So, I'm learning how to use Doyxgen to create documentation. I've pretty much got the single file documentation down, ie, how to specify parameters, place equations, specify output etc.

I'm not sure how I can go about documenting multiple files across multiple objects without having the resulting pdf duplicate the documentation. For instance, in my main file I have:

```
extern double getPMF(.....);
```

I would rather not have that be documented as a main function, but rather as a function in my maths object. The way I'm doing it now, the documentation for that function shows up in the description for my main file c and my maths c file.

How can I go about doing this?

Fix: To clarify, this function gets duplicated in all of my file reference documentation that gets generated. I only want this function to be documented in my maths.c file reference, but it gets added to the header file reference, and any files that need to call it as of now.

Comment: What has your reading of the  (extensive!) documentation for doxygen thaught you?

Answer (score 1):

One quick solution is to mark elements you want Doxygen to ignore as such:

```
/** \cond doxy_ignore */
double getPMF();

/** \endcond */
```

It sounds like the ignored section might cover a large portion of some of your files.